# Spark SQL and Cassandra JOIN

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

My Cassandra schema contains a table with a partition key which is a timestamp, and a `parameter` column which is a clustering key.

Each partition contains 10k+ rows. This is logging data at a rate of 1 partition per second.

On the other hand, users can define "datasets" and I have another table which contains, as a partition key the "dataset name" and a clustering column which is a timestamp referring to the other table (so a "dataset" is a list of partition keys).

Of course what I would like to do looks like an anti-pattern for Cassandra as I'd like to join two tables.

However using Spark SQL I can run such a query and perform the `JOIN`.

```
SELECT * from datasets JOIN data 
    WHERE data.timestamp = datasets.timestamp AND datasets.name = 'my_dataset'
```

Now the question is: is Spark SQL smart enough to read only the partitions of `data` which correspond to the `timestamp`s defined in `datasets`?

Answer (score 4):

Edit: fix the answer with regard to join optimization

> is Spark SQL smart enough to read only the partitions of data which correspond to the timestamps defined in datasets?

No. In fact, since you provide the partition key for the datasets table, the Spark/Cassandra connector will perform **predicate push down** and execute the partition restriction directly in Cassandra with **CQL**. But there will be no predicate push down for the join operation itself unless you use the RDD API with `joinWithCassandraTable()`

See here for all possible predicate push down situations: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/cassandra/BasicCassandraPredicatePushDown.scala

Comment: Are you sure it can push predicates of form `column = column`? If so can you provide some reference. From what I've seen so far Spark consider for only predicates of form `column = value`.

Comment: There is no optimisation for the join but there is predicate push down for **AND datasets.name = 'my_dataset'**. If you want the spark/cassandra connector to optimize the join you need to use the RDD programmatic API (**joinWithCassandraTable**)

Comment: Thanks. So the answer should be no, shouldn't it? As fat as I understand OP asks about the join condition not predicate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments! So that means I should add something like `AND data.timestamp IN (x)` where `x` is a list of timestamps obtained by reading a partition in my `datasets` table. Does that make sense?