# Spark SQL push down of Cassandra UDF?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

Following [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35392521/420892) on Spark SQL I'm wondering if Spark SQL with the Cassandra connector is able to push down the UDF's present in the SQL query to Cassandra UDF (if it exists).

I tried to have a look at the [source](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/cassandra) but I wasn't able to get a clear answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently no support for pushing down udfs.

Comment: At which level should it be done? Cassandra connector or Spark SQL? I would like to send a feature request.

Comment: That's a tough one. Either we need to read the Column Identifier as a function and have that passed to the source (Spark Side) or try to do some crazy interdiction in the Connector. Not sure of a good way to do this at the moment.